# changing network is not working on android pixel(7.1.2)

Tags: android, wifimanager

Changing an access point is not working properly on pixel(7.1.2)

```
private void connect(Context context) {
ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

if (networkInfo == null) return;

if (networkInfo.getExtraInfo() != null &&
    networkInfo.getExtraInfo().contains(HOME_AP_SSID)) return;

List<WifiConfiguration> apList = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
int apNetId = -1;

if (apList != null) {
  for (WifiConfiguration ap : apList) {
    if (ap.SSID != null &&
        ap.SSID.contains(HOME_AP_SSID)) {
      apNetId = ap.networkId;
      break;
    }
  }
}

if (apNetId >= 0) {
  if (wifiManager.disconnect()) {
    wifiManager.enableNetwork(apNetId, true);
  }
}
```

}

After calling wifiManager.enableNetwork(apNetId, true), It changes network actually. But it goes back to previous network after 10 ~ 20 sec.

It only happens on android pixel(7.1.2) among my mobile devices.

Please help.

Comment: Usually android prefers network with internet connection than network without internet connection.

Comment: there is no problem with internet connection. internet connection is fine.

Comment: If the network you try to access through code behaves poorly or breaks down, mobile will automatically connect back to its previous network.

Comment: Changing the network via wifi settings is working well. What is different?